# what is the ? on groovy variables?

Tags: grails, groovy

I saw in some groovy code this:

```
trip.id?.encodeAsHTML()
```

What is the difference between using or not using "id?."?

Comment: In addition to the other replies, I would just like to point out that this syntax is very powerful when combined with the 'Elvis' operator ?: (check out the Groovy Operators link in Matt's reply).

Comment: Too bad that we don't have "Elvis + Assign operator" like x ?= y i.e. assign y to x if x is null

Comment: @fabien would it do that, or assign `y` to `x` if `y` was not `null`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It checks if the object is null or not.
Using it, you can prevent nullpointer exception.

If you use it, you should use it for the whole object (eg: trip.id?.otherstuff?.morestuff?.encodeAsHTML()

Answer (score 4):

It's called the "null-safe dereferencing operator". The difference is that if `trip.id` is null, instead of throwing a `NullPointerException`, it will return `null` as the result of the method call.

Answer (score 1):

It's the Groovy null-safe operator.  It performs a null check before dereferencing the object.  See more on Groovy Operators [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator%28%3F.%29).