# Accessing Class Variables Grails - Difference Between These two

Tags: groovy

Here again. I am confused in two simple things that results same. I am learning Grails and I came through this situation.

`${ClassName.name}` and `${ClassName?.name}` both results same. What is difference of using '?' in this case?

Please Explain difference of using question mark.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the ? on groovy variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302922/what-is-the-on-groovy-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator

Safe Navigation Operator (?.)
The Safe Navigation operator is used to avoid a NullPointerException. Typically when you have a reference to an object you might need to verify that it is not null before accessing methods or properties of the object. To avoid this, the safe navigation operator will simply return null instead of throwing an exception, like so:

```
def user = User.find( "admin" )           //this might be null if 'admin' does not exist
def streetName = user?.address?.street    //streetName will be null if user or user.address is null - no NPE thrown
```